# Coinbase pagination returning {"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Not found"}]}

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, coinbase-api

I am trying to iterate over a paginated list of accounts but when I send a request using the value from "next_uri" I receive an error from the server:
**{"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Not found"}]}**

I am correctly adding headers etc as all other API calls work fine, its just the request using the "next_uri" that is not working. I think I am following the api spec correctly so I am unsure what is the issue and how to fix it.  Does anyone know what is wrong with the code / logic please?

Simplified code:

```
ArrayList<X> results = new ArrayList<>();
String uri = "/v2/accounts";
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = getClient();
while(uri != null){
   T response = client.target("https://api.coinbase.com")
                    .path(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
   results.addAll(response.getData());
   uri = response.getPagination()==null ? null :response.getPagination().getNextUri();
}
return results;
```

The results are this:

Request 1:

> https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts

Response 1: pagination":

> {"ending_before":null,"starting_after":null,"previous_ending_before":null,"next_starting_after":"ef35df6c-a45b-5858-b755-f12a709cf26e","limit":25,"order":"desc","previous_uri":null,**"next_uri":"/v2/accounts?starting_after=ef35df6c-a45b-5858-b755-f12a709cf26e"**},"data":[{....}]

Request 2:

> https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts%3Fstarting_after=ef35df6c-a45b-5858-b755-f12a709cf26e

Response 2:

> {"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Not found"}]}

Answer (score 0):

This was related to how the jax-rs library needs the query params adding.  Just relying on the uri is not enough, the parameters also need adding specifically:

```
target = target.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

so the final code is something like

```
   WebTarget target = client.target(e"https://api.coinbase.com");

        if(params !=null){
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()){
                target = target.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        }
        target = target.path(path);
        return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
```